# how to handle sigterm signal in .net 6 app deployed in azure kubernetes service

Tags: .net-6.0, azure-aks, sigterm

I have a .NET 6 application. This application contains a BackgroundService that is used to handler background jobs. These jobs are fired on a certain time based on different schedules.

I need to implement graceful shutdown when the application is stopping, because there might be some running jobs and I want to complete the jobs before stopping the application.

The app is deployed in Azure Kubernetes Service, when running this command **kubectl delete pod {podname}** to delete a certain pod, I am not able to handle the sigterm and write my logic to handle graceful shutdown.

I am using the `IHostApplicationLifetime` and registering on the `ApplicationStopping` event.

`IHostApplicationLifetime _applicationLifetime;`
`_applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnAppStopping);`

In the docker file I added the below line

`STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM`

The `OnAppStopping` is never fired on AKS.

Comment: BTW do you have `BackgroundService.StopAsync` defined? Is it firing (I suppose not though)?

Comment: Have you tried something from [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5932#issuecomment-439330201)?

Comment: @GuruStron yes, I have it, it is not firing.

Comment: @GuruStron Yeah I added StopSignal in the dockerfile, still not fired. it is very weird, all the documentations mention that it should work.